# How do I share function code between projects?

Tags: azure-functions

What I am building is a SaaS-software for multiple clients. It is mainly based on Azure Storage, Service Bus and Functions v2. It is now built so that every customer will have their own resource group. So all resources are duplicated for every customer. But every case is not identical so I can't directly share all code.

For example there will be different ways to integrate to it and different transformations and validations needed for each customer. Still most code will be identical or some code will be shared by some customers, but not all customers.

How should I build my solution so that I can pick specific functions and also specific versions of them to each customer solution? Without copying code.

For example:
Customer 1: Func1 version 1.0, Func2 version 1.0
Customer 2: Func1 version 1.0, Func2 version 1.1, Func3 1.0

I have many ideas, but the one I would like best is to collect all functions to one DLL and then configure what functions to deploy for each customer? Is it possible to do?

I could of course just disable the unwanted ones, but I don't want a solution where I deploy stuff not wanted and rely on disabling stuff and them staying disabled.

Or is there any other good ways to achieve this?

Comment: You could look into making the stuff real generic and putting it in [Azure Artifacts](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/artifacts/) as a NuGet package.

Answer (score 0):

You could make one resource group with all the functions that have shared logic and from there call the specific logic functions based on the customer. Although this could be a drastic change to your architecture, this way you only need to host the extra customer specific logic and not duplicate all the time. Also for each customer, you can deploy the right version of the customer specific logic function.

#### For your example that would be:

Shared logic resource group:
Function 1 version 1.0

Customer 1 group: 
Function 2 version 1.0

Customer 2 resource group: 
Function 2 version 1.1 
Function 3 version 1.0

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't really answer the question. It isn't really about resource groups but about sharing code. If there was only "shared by all", and then "used by one" functions, this would work. 

But what I have is X amount of functions with different versions, and I want to pick any subset of those to a customer deployment. Customers A, B and C might use SFTP integration and require function X, but Customers D, E might use a REST API and require function Y instead and Customer F might need version 1.1 of function Y.

I could just copy code, but imagine 100 customers